# Bash - Read lines from file with intervals

Tags: bash, shell

I need to read all lines of the file separating at intervals. A function will execute a command with each batch of lines.

Lines range example:

```
1 - 20
21 - 50
51 - 70
...
```

I tried with the sed command in a forloop, but the range does not go to the end of the file. For example, a file with 125 lines reads up to 121, missing lines to reach the end.

I commented on the sed line because in this loop the range goes up to 121 and the COUNT is 125.

```
TEXT=`cat wordlist.txt`
COUNT=$( wc -l <<<$TEXT )
for i in $(seq 1 20 $COUNT);
do
echo "$i"
#sed -n "1","${i}p"<<<$TEXT
done
```

Output:

```
1
21
41
61
81
101
121
```

Thanks!

Comment: show us the code you tried

Comment: I put the code in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Are the ranges supposed to be different sizes? You have two ranges with 20 lines, while the middle range has 30 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix - ensure the last line is processed by throwing `$COUNT` on the end of of values assigned to `i`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 20 $COUNT) $COUNT;
do
echo "$i"
done

1
21
41
61
81
101
121
125
```

If `COUNT` happens to be the same as the last value generated by `seq` then we'll need to add some logic to skip the second time around; for example, if `COUNT=121` then we'll want to skip the second time around when `i=121`, eg:

```
# assume COUNT=121

lasti=0
for i in $(seq 1 20 $COUNT) $COUNT;
do
[ $lasti = $COUNT ] && break
echo "$i"
lasti=$i
done

1
21
41
61
81
101
121
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your response (`$COUNT]` without a blank).

Comment: The last $count variable in forloop is that's what was missing. Thank you!
`for i in $(seq 1 $interval $count) $count;`

Comment: correct; by throwing `$COUNT` on the end I added one more item to the list of `i` values